# Cannot add to a c++cli collections::generic::list

Tags: c++-cli

I made a simple tree class like this:

```
public ref class SimpleTreeNode {
public:
    String^ Data;
    List<SimpleTreeNode^>^ Children = gcnew List<SimpleTreeNode^>;
}
```

however, when i go and try to add stuff like this:

```
auto^ nstn = gcnew SimpleTreeNode();
nstn->Children->Add(gcnew SimpleTreeNode());
```

it says "Error: function "System::collections::generic::List::Add [with T=SimpleTreeNode^]" cannot be called with the given argument list

argument types are: (SimpleTreeNode^)
object type is: System::Collections::Generic::List^"

what am I missing here? This should work, no?

Comment: Yeah, I think it should work.

Comment: but it totally doesn't. I ended up adding a method "AddChild(SimpleTreeNode^ n) {Children->Add(n)}" to it and that works.

Answer (score 1):

For your case you should use keyword auto without the hat for both ref and value types. Like this:

```
auto nstn = gcnew SimpleTreeNode();
auto cN = nstn->Children->Count;

nstn->Children->Add(gcnew SimpleTreeNode());
auto cN2 = nstn->Children->Count;
```